# C# How to calculate a Point with a right angle between two Points and equidistant

Tags: c#, .net, math

For a given point X1 and X2, how can I calculate the point X3 (red) that is equidistant to X1 and X2 and has a right angle between them?

[image]

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/pythagoras.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a maths problem primarily, rather than a programming one. If the OP had already done the maths part and needed help with the implementation in a particular language and showed their attempt so-far, it would be more on topic.

Comment: You say "*the* point X3" (emphasis mine), but there are two such points in general (consider reflecting X3 in the line joining X1 to X2). Do you want both? If not, what's the criterion for selecting which of the two to return? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that there are two points that satisfy your criteria: one below the line, one above. We can find both.

Now, we will handle this by three cases:

1. the line passing through (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is a vertical line. In this case, find the midpoint ((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2), and the points you're looking for will have the same Y coordinate and will have X coordinates to the left and right displaced by an amount |y2-y1|/2 (because the triangles formed will be 45-45-90 right triangles).
2. the line passing through (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is a horizontal line. In this case, find the midpoint as above, and the points will have the same X-coordinate, and the Y coordinate displaced by an amount |x2-x1|/2, as above.
3. the line passing through (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is neither horizontal nor is it vertical. In that case, calculate the slope of the line m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) and take the negative inverse n = -1/m. All lines perpendicular to our line have slope n. Now, find the midpoint as in cases 1 and 2. Finally, we must find the two displacements (dx, dy) such that dy/dx = n and dy^2 + dx^2 = ((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2) / 2.

We can use the first equation to write dy = ndx and then replace into the second equation:

```
dy^2 + dx^2 = ((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2) / 4
n^2 dx^2 + dx^2 = ((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2) / 4
(n^2 + 1)dx^2 = ((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2) / 4
dx^2 = ((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2) / 4(n^2 + 1)
dx = +- sqrt(((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2) / 4(n^2 + 1))
```

Once you find dx, you can find dy from dy = ndx. Note there will always be two solutions; if you want one and not the other, we need a rule to know which one you want.

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary. `x3 = (x1 + x2 + y2 - y1) / 2`, `y3 = (x1 - x2 + y1 + y2)/2` is all you need; it works in all three cases. (And to get the "other" point, `x3 = (x1 + x2 + y1 - y2)/2`, `y3 = (y1 + y2 + x2 - x1)/2`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I'd be interested in seeing the derivation of that if you want to post it. I imagine my case 3 solution reduces to this algebraically (and my case 1 and case 2 solutions are probably special cases)

Comment: Essentially, start from the midpoint between `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, and draw a vector that's perpendicular to the line joining the two points, and of half the length of that line. IOW, we want the vector that you get by rotating `((x2 - x1)/2, (y2  - y1)/2)` by a quarter turn, which is `((y2 - y1)/2, (x1 - x2)/2)`. Adding that to the midpoint gives the expressions above. (And yes, I'd agree that your case 3 solution likely ends up reducing to this.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Wow when you put it like that, it is much simpler. Looks like where I went astray was in actually calculating the slope, should have just left it as rise and run without doing the division. Nicely done